# MERGE into getting stuck all of a sudden

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, merge, ssis

I have a stored procedure that is getting stuck on the merge into all of a sudden but has been working fine for years. Any advice ? The SP is in Oracle SQL developer and it is being executed in a Visual Studios SSIS package

Query below:

```
MERGE INTO CORE_APPT C 
  USING (
          SELECT DISTINCT
            TST_TKR_ID,
            TST_TKR_ID_SRC,
            APPT_ID_SRC,
            APPT_CRETN_DTE,
            APNTMT_DT,  
            ETS_APNTMT_ID,
            ETS_TST_CNTR,
            TST_STS_TYP_DESC,
            APPT_STS_TYP,
            TST_DLVR_MTHD_TYP_CDE,
            DLVR_GRP_TYP,
            TST_LNCH_TM,
            TRNSCTN_ID,
            TST_PKG_ID,
            RND_TRIP_TST_FLG,
            UPDT_DTE_TM,
            PROD_ID,
            ACTN_DTE_TM,
            TST_DURN,
            BRKRG_APPT_UPDT_DTM,
            TST_APPT_TYP_CDE,
            CNCL_MKUP_RSN_TYP,
            DLNQNT_HLD_FLG,
            TST_TKR_TST_UPDT_DTE_TM,
            SCR_HLD_LVL_TYP_CDE,
            SCR_CNCL_FLG,
            ETS_CANDTE_SCR_HLD_FLG,
            TST_CNTR_HLD_FLG,
            TST_ADM_HLD_FLG,
            ETS_SCR_CNCL_FLG,
            TST_ADM_HLD_RSN_CDE,
            TST_CNTR_HLD_RSN_CDE,
            ETS_CANDTE_SCR_HLD_RSN_CDE,
            ETS_SCR_CNCL_RSN_CDE,
            DLNQNT_HLD_RSN_CDE,
            TST_TKR_SCR_STS_TYP_CDE,
            TST_TKR_SCR_STS_RSN_TYP_CDE,
            PYMT_NO,
            DATA_SRCE AS DATA_SRCE,
            CURRENT_FLAG,
            PRGRM_TYP,
            sysdate as RCD_CRTD_DTE,
            user as RCD_CRTD_USER,
            REG_SYS_ID AS REG_SYS_ID,
            TST_NAM AS TST_NAM,
            CNTRY_SETL_RSP AS CNTRY_SETL_RSP
          FROM STG_CMMN_APPT A
          WHERE A.CURRENT_FLAG = 'Y'
        ) S
    ON (C.APPT_ID_SRC = S.APPT_ID_SRC
        AND C.REG_SYS_ID = S.REG_SYS_ID
        AND C.DATA_SRCE = S.DATA_SRCE)  -- added in EREG4.0 changes
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET C.CURRENT_FLAG = 'N'
        WHERE C.CURRENT_FLAG = 'Y'
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
    (
            C.TST_TKR_ID,
            C.TST_TKR_ID_SRC,
            C.APPT_ID_SRC,
            C.APPT_CRETN_DTE,
            C.APNTMT_DT,
            C.ETS_APNTMT_ID,
            C.TST_CNTR_ID_SRC,
            C.TST_STS_TYP_DESC,
            C.APPT_STS_TYP,
            C.TST_DLVR_MTHD_TYP_CDE,
            C.DLVR_GRP_TYP,
            C.TST_LNCH_TM,
            C.TRNSCTN_ID,
            C.TST_PKG_ID,
            C.RND_TRIP_TST_FLG,
            C.UPDT_DTE_TM,
            C.PROD_ID,
            C.ACTN_DTE_TM,
            C.TST_DURN,
            C.BRKRG_APPT_UPDT_DTM,
            C.TST_APPT_TYP_CDE,
            C.CNCL_MKUP_RSN_TYP,
            C.DLNQNT_HLD_FLG,
            C.TST_TKR_TST_UPDT_DTE_TM,
            C.SCR_HLD_LVL_TYP_CDE,
            C.SCR_CNCL_FLG,
            C.ETS_CANDTE_SCR_HLD_FLG,
            C.TST_CNTR_HLD_FLG,
            C.TST_ADM_HLD_FLG,
            C.ETS_SCR_CNCL_FLG,
            C.TST_ADM_HLD_RSN_CDE,
            C.TST_CNTR_HLD_RSN_CDE,
            C.ETS_CANDTE_SCR_HLD_RSN_CDE,
            C.ETS_SCR_CNCL_RSN_CDE,
            C.DLNQNT_HLD_RSN_CDE,
            C.TST_TKR_SCR_STS_TYP_CDE,
            C.TST_TKR_SCR_STS_RSN_TYP_CDE,
            C.PYMT_NO,
            C.DATA_SRCE,
            C.CURRENT_FLAG,
            C.PGM_TYP,
            C.RCD_CRTD_DTE,
            C.RCD_CRTD_USER,
            C.REG_SYS_ID,
            C.TST_NAM,
            C.CNTRY_SETL_RSP
    )
    VALUES
    ( 
            S.TST_TKR_ID,
            S.TST_TKR_ID_SRC,
            S.APPT_ID_SRC,
            S.APPT_CRETN_DTE,
            S.APNTMT_DT,
            S.ETS_APNTMT_ID,
            S.ETS_TST_CNTR,
            S.TST_STS_TYP_DESC,
            S.APPT_STS_TYP,
            S.TST_DLVR_MTHD_TYP_CDE,
            S.DLVR_GRP_TYP,
            S.TST_LNCH_TM,
            S.TRNSCTN_ID,
            S.TST_PKG_ID,
            S.RND_TRIP_TST_FLG,
            S.UPDT_DTE_TM,
            S.PROD_ID,
            S.ACTN_DTE_TM,
            S.TST_DURN,
            S.BRKRG_APPT_UPDT_DTM,
            S.TST_APPT_TYP_CDE,
            S.CNCL_MKUP_RSN_TYP,
            S.DLNQNT_HLD_FLG,
            S.TST_TKR_TST_UPDT_DTE_TM,
            S.SCR_HLD_LVL_TYP_CDE,
            S.SCR_CNCL_FLG,
            S.ETS_CANDTE_SCR_HLD_FLG,
            S.TST_CNTR_HLD_FLG,
            S.TST_ADM_HLD_FLG,
            S.ETS_SCR_CNCL_FLG,
            S.TST_ADM_HLD_RSN_CDE,
            S.TST_CNTR_HLD_RSN_CDE,
            S.ETS_CANDTE_SCR_HLD_RSN_CDE,
            S.ETS_SCR_CNCL_RSN_CDE,
            S.DLNQNT_HLD_RSN_CDE,
            S.TST_TKR_SCR_STS_TYP_CDE,
            S.TST_TKR_SCR_STS_RSN_TYP_CDE,
            S.PYMT_NO,
            S.DATA_SRCE,
            S.CURRENT_FLAG,
            S.PRGRM_TYP,
            S.RCD_CRTD_DTE,
            S.RCD_CRTD_USER,
            S.REG_SYS_ID,
            S.TST_NAM,
            S.CNTRY_SETL_RSP
    )

    ;
```

TIA!

Comment: Your query looks fine. What's the explain plan say? Has anything major changed with the data or the server? There's a lot of potential things to look at here.

Comment: Nothing major changing with the data besides a constant flow of new records. The procedure that loads the tables that this procedure is pulling from has been migrated to a cloud server so is using db links. That would be the only change. I was thinking on changing this from a merge to an insert update to break up the steps(?) not sure how to make this query to that though..

Comment: Also you are saying that you are using a stored procedure? Maybe the problem it's not with Merge. Have you done other checks on procedure?

Comment: Does "stuck" mean that it is running without error but just taking longer than normal?  My guess would be you're encountering a block.  Maybe the migration to the cloud has increased the latency of this or some other session so row-level locks are getting held longer or processes that didn't used to run at the same time are now running at the same time.

Comment: I would say stuck as in taking longer than normal but its never finishing and when I count the rows that are being pulled in during the run its never changing which is telling me that its not pulling anything in only problem is that it is never failing so I'm receiving no error